# Heroku ps:exec cannot connect or ssh into dyno

Tags: heroku

```
heroku ps:exec -a homehost-demo
Establishing credentials... error
 ▸    Could not connect to dyno!
 ▸    Check if the dyno is running with `heroku ps'
```

running `ps` returns

```
Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 544h 27m (98%)
Free dyno usage for this app: 1h 17m (0%)
For more information on dyno sleeping and how to upgrade, see:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping

=== web (Free): npm start (1)
web.1: idle 2019/04/14 15:34:54 -0400
```

this command works for the other applications hosted on heroku

Comment: fixed after restarting

Comment: What kind do you restart?

Comment: Dyno restart, I guess.